# How to delete a particular sentence from a file using line number in Python

Tags: python, file, nltk

I want to delete particular lines which contain stopwords or matching string:

```
import nltk
from nltk import *
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import time

Mywords = 'hello', 'there', 'been'
#stopwords for matching in the sentences.
f = open('hello.txt','rU')
raw = f.read()
sent = word_tokenize(raw)
#tokenize the words.
from nltk.tokenize import wordpunct_tokenize
punct = wordpunct_tokenize(raw)
sent = sent_tokenize(raw)
length = len(sent)

print(length)
i = 0
while(i<length):
    i = i + 1
    time.sleep(2)
    #print(sent[i])
    if i <length:
        #print(sent[i])
        thisWord = (word_tokenize(sent[i]))
        for word in thisWord:
            if word in Mywords:
                #print(thisWord, word)
                print("yes: ", sent[i])
            else:
                print("No:", sent[i])

    else:
        print("End of Line")
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you edit the question to include this.

Comment: i want to delete the sentences which contains words='hello','been',there' from my text file and show remaining sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really delete lines from a file, but you can write all the lines that do not contain any of your stop words to another file.

The following script first takes your list of stop words and converts them into a `set()`. It then reads your input file a line at a time. For each line to uses the `nltk.word_tokenize()` to create a list of words. It converts this list of words into a set and gets the intersection of this with the stop words. If this is not empty then there must have been some stop words present. It then shows the stop words that it found.

If none are found, it writes the remaining lines to an `output.txt` file:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

# Full list of stop words from nltk
#stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

stop_words = set(['hello', 'there', 'been'])

with open('input.txt','rU') as f_input, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    for line in f_input:
        line_words = set(word_tokenize(line))
        stop_words_present = line_words & stop_words

        if stop_words_present:
            print("Yes: '{}' contains {}".format(line.strip(), stop_words_present))     # Contains at least one stop word
        else:
            print("No:", line.strip())      # Contains non stop stops
            f_output.write(line)
```

Note `nltk` has a complete list of English stop words that you can make use of, just change the line above. You may need to first install this if it cannot find it as follows. Run the following mini-script:

```
import nltk

nltk.download()
```

This will display a download utility allowing you to get the `stopwords` as follows:

[image: NLTK download helper]

Select `Corpora`, scroll down to `stopwords` and click the `Download` button.

Comment: thanks for that code martin it will really help me.

Comment: You are welcome, Don't forget to click on the grey tick next to the answer, to accept the solution when you are done.